# Erro Java relatório em PDF

Tags: java

Tenho um programinha java para geração de relatórios em PDF.
O problema é que, toda vez que vou enviar o PDF por Email, ele abre o PDF na tela.
Onde posso alterar, para que ele não abra na tela ao enviar por Email?
segue o meu código:

```
public class Main {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
    String dirConf = args[0];

    if ((new File(dirConf)).exists())
        try {
            Map<String, String> param = (new ReadXML()).getParams(dirConf);
            server = (String) param.get("server");
            port = (String) param.get("port");
            database = (String) param.get("database");
            usuario = (String) param.get("user");
            senha = (String) param.get("password");
            url = (String) param.get("url");
            type = (String) param.get("type");
            folder = (String) param.get("folder");
            primary = (String) param.get("primary");
            secundary = (String) param.get("secundary");
            idiomas.add(primary);
            idiomas.add(secundary);
            name = getName(url);
            destFileName = (new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(folder)))
                    .append(name).append((String) param.get("id"))
                    .append(".").append(type).toString();
            sourceFileName = url;
            connection = (new ConectaProgress()).conectar(server, port,
                    database, usuario, senha);
            tempSet = param.keySet();
            Object object;
            for (Iterator<String> iterator = tempSet.iterator(); iterator
                    .hasNext(); paramJasper.put(object.toString(),
                    (String) param.get(object)))
                object = iterator.next();

            for (Iterator<String> iterator1 = idiomas.iterator(); iterator1
                    .hasNext();) {
                String string = (String) iterator1.next();
                label = (new DAO()).carregaLabel(connection, string);
                tempSet = label.keySet();
                String string1;
                for (Iterator<String> iterator2 = tempSet.iterator(); iterator2
                        .hasNext(); paramJasper.put(string1,
                        (String) label.get(string1)))
                    string1 = (String) iterator2.next();

            }

            (new Main()).exportar(type, destFileName, sourceFileName,
                    paramJasper);
            File destFile = new File(destFileName);
            if (destFile.exists())
                desktop.open(destFile);
            System.out.println("ok\nrelatorio gerado com sucesso.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Excecao(e);
        }
    else
        throw new Excecao(new Exception("arquivo nao encontrado."));
}

private static String getName(String url) {
    char name[] = (new File(url)).getName().toCharArray();
    url = "";
    char ac[];
    int j = (ac = name).length;
    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        char c = ac[i];
        if (c == '.')
            break;
        url = (new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(url))).append(c).toString();
    }

    return url;
}

private void exportar(String type, String destFileName,
        String sourceFileName, Map<String, String> paramJasper)
        throws IOException {
    paramJasper.put("icn",
            getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("icn.png")
                    .toString());

    paramJasper.put("logo",
            getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("logo.jpg")
                    .toString());
    JasperPrint relatorioFinal = null;
    FontFactory.register(getClass().getClassLoader()
            .getResource("ARIALUNI.TTF").toString());
    try {
        relatorioFinal = JasperFillManager.fillReport(sourceFileName,
                paramJasper, connection);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Excecao(e);
    }
    if (type.equals("pdf"))
        try {
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(relatorioFinal,
                                    destFileName);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Excecao(e);
        }
    if (type.equals("xls"))
        try {
            JRXlsExporter xls = new JRXlsExporter();
            xls.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT,
                    relatorioFinal);
            xls.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME,
                    destFileName);
            xls.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET,
                    Boolean.FALSE);
            xls.setParameter(
                    JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND,
                    Boolean.FALSE);
            xls.setParameter(
                    JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS,
                    Boolean.TRUE);
            xls.exportReport();
        } catch (JRException e) {
            throw new Excecao(e);
        }
    if (type.equals("csv"))
        try {
            JRCsvExporter csv = new JRCsvExporter();
            csv.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT,
                    relatorioFinal);
            csv.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME,
                    destFileName);
            csv.exportReport();
        } catch (JRException e) {
            throw new Excecao(e);
        }
    if (type.equals("ods"))
        try {
            JROdsExporter ods = new JROdsExporter();
            ods.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT,
                    relatorioFinal);
            ods.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME,
                    destFileName);
            ods.exportReport();
        } catch (JRException e) {
            throw new Excecao(e);
        }

    if (type.equals("pre")) {
        JasperViewer jv = new JasperViewer(relatorioFinal);
        jv.setExtendedState(6);
        jv.setTitle(" RelatorioPdf");
        java.awt.image.BufferedImage imagem = ImageIO.read(getClass()
                .getClassLoader().getResource("imagem.png"));
        jv.setIconImage(imagem);
        jv.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: Foi você que desenvolveu o código? Creio que no `if (destFile.exists())    desktop.open(destFile);` que está seu "problema", pois ele faz essa verificação depois de gerar o arquivo.

Comment: @user21886 achou alguma soluçao?

Answer (score 1):

Caro,

No final do try tem os comandos:

```
File destFile = new File(destFileName);
if (destFile.exists())
     desktop.open(destFile); <--- este principalmente.
```

Eles servem para abrir o arquivo pelo sistema operacional.

Olhando o método exportar, se você passar o tipo pré, ele também apresentará a janela (o `JasperViewer` serve para isso):

```
if (type.equals("pre")) {
    JasperViewer jv = new JasperViewer(relatorioFinal);
    jv.setExtendedState(6);
    jv.setTitle(" RelatorioPdf");
    java.awt.image.BufferedImage imagem = ImageIO.read(getClass()
            .getClassLoader().getResource("imagem.png"));
    jv.setIconImage(imagem);
    jv.setVisible(true);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remova a isso

```
 if (destFile.exists())
                desktop.open(destFile);
```